# Everytime my page is refreshed, the colors of each letter are randomized

Tags: javascript, html, css

Every time my page is refreshed, the colors of each letter are randomized. How can I get it so that there are two colors, and just alternating them.

Here are the HTML colors:

011a39
29c3fd

```js
// Menu Visual
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var tempText = "";

for(let x in myText.textContent){
  var rnd =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 +  1));
  var rndBounce =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 5) + 5) / 10;
  if(rnd === 0){
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else if (rnd === 1) {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #29c3fd; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  }
}
myText.innerHTML = tempText;
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from { top: 10px; }
  to { top: 0; }
}

#textContainer {
  position: absolute;
top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#myText {
  text-align: center;
}

#myText>span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaijaan', cursive; 
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="textContainer">
  <div id="myText">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to randomize for each letter, just on load, try this out:

```js
// Menu Visual
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var rnd = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1 : 0; // set once, if you always want it to start with the same color, then just set this to 0 or 1;
var tempText = "";

for(let x = 0, length = myText.textContent.length; x < length; x ++){
  var rndBounce =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 5) + 5) / 10;

  if(x % 2 === rnd) { // based on if rnd is 0 or 1
      tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else {
      tempText += "<span style='color: #29c3fd; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  }
}
myText.innerHTML = tempText;
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from { top: 10px; }
  to { top: 0; }
}

#textContainer {
  position: absolute;
top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#myText {
  text-align: center;
}

#myText>span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaijaan', cursive; 
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="textContainer">
  <div id="myText">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this will work for you. If you want other colors, just change them inside the `colors` array

```js
// Menu Visual
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var tempText = "";
var colors = ["#011a39", "#29c3fd"];
for(let x in myText.textContent){
var rndBounce =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 5) + 5) / 10;
    //you can use the modulus operator (%) to guarantee that the counter variable keeps alternating between 1 and 0 (the colors array length)
    tempText += "<span style='color: " + colors[x % 2] +"; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
}
myText.innerHTML = tempText;
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  from { top: 10px; }
  to { top: 0; }
}

#textContainer {
  position: absolute;
top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
}

#myText {
  text-align: center;
}

#myText>span {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 5em;
  font-family: 'Baloo Bhaijaan', cursive; 
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="textContainer">
  <div id="myText">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was getting ready to post a similar answer, you should mention that you are using the modulus operator to alternate between `0` and `1`

Comment: `How can I get it so that there are two colors, and just alternating them.` after page loaded, each time refresh should alternating the color, not random again.

Comment: @DanielH that is what my code does. It uses the modulus operator to alternate the colors. The random part is OP's code, for the bounce

Comment: @Arturthetemplar oh u dont need a counter, `x` is the index, you can just use that.

Comment: @Arturthetemplar might I misunderstand the question, I thought he wants alternating color each time refresh. lol

Comment: @DanielH you are right, I didn't needed the counter. Changed it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, you are randomizing the colors in this line:

> var rnd =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 +  1));

If you want to alternate just do something like this :

```
int i = 0;
for(let x in myText.textContent){
  var rnd =  i % 2;
  var rndBounce =  Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 5) + 5) / 10;
  if(rnd === 0){
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else if (rnd === 1) {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #29c3fd; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  }
  i += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sessionStorage` or `cookie`, when you first load the page you random the color for each letter, then when you refresh you should **only alternating** them.

Therefore it is good to use `sessionStorage` to hold the rnd number you got from last time, only get new random if a `sessionStorage` for that letter can no be found.

Try it yourself here (refresh to alternating)

> ### https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/db54ttuq/

```
// Menu Visual
var myText = document.getElementById('myText');
var tempText = "";

for (let x in myText.textContent) {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (2 - 0 + 1));
  var rndBounce = Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 5) + 5) / 10;

  if (sessionStorage.getItem('item' + x)) {
    rnd = sessionStorage.getItem('item' + x) === '1' ? 0 : 1;
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem('item' + x, rnd);

  if (rnd === 0) {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else if (rnd === 1) {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #29c3fd; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  } else {
    tempText += "<span style='color: #011a39; animation-duration: " + rndBounce + "s'>" + myText.textContent[x] + "</span>";
  }
}
myText.innerHTML = tempText;
```